# Installing SDKs (JDK, Maven, Gradle) on WSL and Windows?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to install some SDKs (JDK, Maven, Gradle) using SDKMAN in WSL. If later I need to run some of them in Windows app - should I install those SDKs in Windows as well? Or I can simply edit the PATH variable in Windows pointing to those SDKs installed in WSL? Or vice versa - install first in Windows and export PATH in WSL?

Or they are completely isolated and I should install Maven/Gradle both in Windows and in WSL if I want to run them in Windows and WSL?

Comment: I've asked a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1216231/how-to-use-the-windows-installation-of-java-from-bashonwindows10)

Answer (score 0):

You should at least install the JDK on Windows, since it contains platform specific binaries. The Java based SDKs should work on Windows as well, even if installed on WSL.